# If Column Contains String then put value for that row

Tags: r, string

I have data that looks like this:

```
A                              B
Manager, Sales
Manager
Manager, Marketing
Manager, Marketing, Sales
```

How do I make column B fill-in with "Yes" or "No" if Column A contains Sales, Marketing, or Sales, or Marketing?

Final data should look like this:

```
A                             B
Manager, Sales                Yes
Manager                       No
Manager, Marketing            Yes
Manager, Sales, Marketing     Yes
```

Comment: If this is for processing purposes, you might consider `logical` instead of `character` for your `B` column: it more clearly expresses what you expect to go in there, is faster for logical operations (e.g., *"do something where true"*), and preempts the possibility of slightly different values in there (`yes`/`Yes`). Use the right data type for the job: if you need a variable indicating a boolean condition, use `logical`; ordinal? `integer` or `factor`; etc. If you are concerned about rendering of the table later (and have mid-stage processing), convert to strings *then*. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(B = case_when(str_detect(A, 'Sales|Marketing') ~ 'Yes', TRUE ~ 'No'))
                          A   B
1            Manager, Sales Yes
2                   Manager  No
3        Manager, Marketing Yes
4 Manager, Marketing, Sales Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ifelse`

```
df$B <- ifelse(grepl('Sales|Marketing', df$A), "Yes", "No")
```